# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'delf'? and 3 import files are unavailable on github

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, feature-selection

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROhmf.png)I am duplicating results of research paper "Large-Scale Image Retrieval with Attentive Deep Local Features",

System Description: Ubuntu 16.04
Directory: /home/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/models/research/delf/delf/python/examples 
Tensorflow: Only CPU version

#### Describe the problem

I have followed steps given in link: "https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/delf"
and its sub-link: "https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/delf/EXTRACTION_MATCHING.md".

But getting following error: 
    File "extract_features.py", line 35, in 
        from delf import feature_extractor
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'delf'

My second issue is that, **init**.py file available local path: "/home/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/models/research/delf/delf", contain following imports:

```
from delf.protos import datum_pb2
from delf.protos import delf_config_pb2
from delf.protos import feature_pb2
```

But unfortunately, these three files are not available on github, from where should i get these files?

Comment: Have you followed the [install instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/delf/INSTALL_INSTRUCTIONS.md)?

Comment: Yes I have followed install instructions, and then executed commands, and at last stage of installation instruction i got this error: **bold**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/hanif/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/models/research/delf/delf/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from delf.protos import datum_pb2
ImportError: cannot import name 'datum_pb2']

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3451

Comment: Thanks vivek kumar for your prompt response, but files are not available in mentioned link. Either hidden or whatever is the issue but i am unable to see them.

Comment: Hi, I just tried installing the module and am able to install it successfully. Are you sure you followed each step (including installing the [object_detection module](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md)

Comment: Thankyou so much vivek kumar, my problem is solved. All that I was doing wrong by not running this instruction while opening new terminal: [# From tensorflow/models/research/
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved. All that I was doing wrong by not running this instruction while opening new terminal: 
From tensorflow/models/research/ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:pwd:pwd/slim